# Can I watch a folder for new files created?

Tags: node.js, linux, npm, filesystems

I am working on some projects with git, and most of these projects are using nodejs. Recently, while I am developing in these projects, some files were duplicated for some reason, and I couldn't find out the reason. Is there any way I can monitor the entire project for new duplicated files with the process that did the duplication?

I've heard that `lsof` is gonna do the job, but man page tells me that this is for monitoring the opened files of a process. And I found people saying `inotify` is gonna do the job, but it doesn't seem support MacOS.

What's odd is that the duplication is not always on the same file, it could be a `*.json`, a `*.jpeg`, or etc,. so I can't track a specific file for duplication. Also, I am not using any automatic integration tools or IDE for the development.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is [`fs.FSWatcher()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_fswatcher) or [`fs.watch()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watch_filename_options_listener) what you want?

Comment: Your tag says linux, your text speaks of MacOS ... is this relevant to both?

Comment: MacOS is what I am using right now, but I think it would be helpful if there's a general solution for the problem.